# Change color of child node

Tags: swift, ios8, scenekit

Currently when I change child's node color it will led to color change of all another child nodes, which I don't want.

I change color of the child node this way:

```
let materials = node.geometry?.materials as! [SCNMaterial]
let material = materials[0]
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.grayColor()
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using shared geometry?  That may explain the fact that a color change on one node changes the color on other nodes.  You may want to try unsharing the geometry and then unsharing the material.

Comment: @sambro I use car model from https://github.com/jamesfolk/SceneKitVehicleDemo. I don't know if it is shared geometry or not. I'm trying to change color of the wheel, and wheel is child node inside of this file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [@sambro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943553/sambro) comment and [@rickster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster) code, here is the ready answer:

```
// Un-share the geometry by copying
node.geometry = node.geometry!.copy() as? SCNGeometry
// Un-share the material, too
node.geometry?.firstMaterial = node.geometry?.firstMaterial!.copy() as? SCNMaterial
// Now, we can change node's material without changing parent and other childs:
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Answer (score 13):

By default, if you have multiple nodes that have the same `SCNGeometry` instance assigned to them, then those nodes also have the same materials. Changing a material changes the appearance of all nodes using that material.

An `SCNGeometry` object doesn't directly represent geometry data — it's actually just a lightweight representation of the association between a set of geometry data and a set of materials. So, when you want to render the same geometry on multiple nodes with different materials, just copy the geometry object... they'll still share the underlying data, so there's negligible render-time cost, but you'll be able to change their materials independently.

After you copy the geometry, you can change the *sets of* materials on the two geometries independently, but those sets are still sharing the same `SCNMaterial` instances. (This is useful because a geometry can have multiple materials, and each material is a set of several properties, so it's efficient to share them wherever possible.) So you can either assign new materials to each geometry, or un-share the materials.

```
// Using copy as a way to get two nodes with the same material
// (but your scene might already have two such nodes)
let node2 = node1.copy() as! SCNNode 

// Right now, node2 is sharing geometry. This changes the color of both:
node1.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()

// Un-share the geometry by copying
node2.geometry = node1.geometry!.copy()
// Un-share the material, too
node2.geometry?.firstMaterial = node1.geometry!.firstMaterial!.copy() as? SCNMaterial
// Now, we can change node2's material without changing node1's:
node2.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
```

There's a good discussion of this in the WWDC 2014 talk on [Building a Game with SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=610). The relevant bit is at about 37:15 in the video or slide 159 in the PDF.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Probably because node1 should be replaced with node2, but I can't figure it out how.

Comment: I've got this exact code working in a playground... you might want to make sure that the things you've added to your scene are the `node1` and `node2` that you're expecting, perhaps?

Comment: To clarify:
Have you used a model from ```car model from github.com/jamesfolk/SceneKitVehicleDemo.```? What I'm trying to do is to change color of the wheel of the car.

Comment: That sample code is originally from Apple, BTW — look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html) for the original download and any updates Apple puts there in the future.

Comment: To get at the wheels in that scene, you have two issues: first, you need to grab the right node — not the car itself, but one of the nodes holding the wheel geometry (named things like `wheelRearR` in the scene). Second, the way the model appears in the shipping sample, the tire and the inside of the wheel look different due to texture mapping, so you won't be able to keep that by assigning a solid-color material. But you should be able to grab one of the wheel nodes, unshare its geometry and materials, and assign it a solid color.

Comment: @rikster I figured it out how to make it work, thanks. There is no need to copy node, just to unshare its geometry and materials. Can I modify your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It has been simplified now

```
    let searchNode = node.childNode(withName: "YOUR_CHILD_NODE_NAME", recursively: true)
    searchNode?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
```

Here, it searches the complete tree. Child node, sub child node and so on till it finds a node with the specific name.